# My Path for CSS and javascript is not working and giving url like %7B%7B%?

Tags: laravel

This is my route for main/index.html

```
Route::get('main-index', function () {
   return view('main.index');
});
```

i tried to give css path like this

```
  <link href="{{ URL::asset('backend/dist/css/tabler.min.css') }}">
    //and this also 
  <link href="{{ asset('backend') }}/dist/css/tabler.min.css">
```

But its nor working and in console table.min.css not found

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20URL::asset('backend/dist/css/tabler.min.css')%20%7D%7D
```

HOw to solve this ?

Comment: change main/index.html to main/index.blade.php. this syntax only work on blade file

Comment: **{{ }}** is used for `Echoing Data`, this is not working on your side, because you are not using blade engine. change `main/index.html` to `main/index.blade.php`